# Delete 2 Lines From hosts

Tags: batch-file

I need to remove 2 lines from my hosts file in a Batch File:

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
```

So I wrote this code, but have some problems:

```
@Echo Off
Set hosts=%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
Attrib -R %hosts%

FindStr /V /I /C:"www.domain1.com" "%hosts%" > "d:\1.txt"
FindStr /V /I /C:"www.domain2.com" "d:\1.txt" > "d:\2.txt"
```

Well this work and d:\2.txt is made the way I want, so now I must delete 1.txt and replace/move 2.txt to hosts
I have some questions to update and make my code simpler:

Can I merge the above 2 FindStr lines into 1 line without making a 3rd file?
I don't know why for example this one does not work, while it should work?

```
FindStr /V /I /C:"www.domain1.com" "%hosts%" > "%hosts%"
```

This makes the whole file empty!
Please advise, not using Find :)

Comment: Update: I need to remove all the lines that contains www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com

Comment: So maybe those 2 strings do not exists, in that case, file becomes empty, plz help :((

Comment: `"%hosts%" > "%hosts%"` won't work as the file is read line by line. Remove the `/c` and have both domain names separated by a space.

Comment: `shell` and `batch-file` are two completely different things. `shell` refers to POSIX shell present on Unix/Linux. `batch-file` is the DOS incarnation of script for the `cmd.exe` interpreter on windows. From context, you want the `batch-file` tag and can remove the other.

Comment: I have updated my script to this:

Comment: FindStr /V /I "www.r2rdownload.com www.elephantafiles.com" "%hosts%" > "d:\hosts2.txt"

Comment: It works, still 2 problems: I do have to make a 2nd temp file and cannot directly  save hosts? And also each line is removed but vbNewLine at the end of line is not removed, I mean blank lines remains, anyway to remove empty lines at the end of file?

Comment: `findstr /v "^$" file.txt` See `findstr /?`.

Answer (score 1):

The complete command line to search **case-insensitive** and **literally** in all lines in `hosts` file for either `www.r2rdownload.com` or `www.elephantafiles.com` and output all lines **not containing** one of those two strings is:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V "www.r2rdownload.com www.elephantafiles.com" "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

The option `/L` is important as otherwise the two strings separated by a space are interpreted as regular expression strings with `.` being interpreted as placeholder for any character except newline character.

Another possibility for exactly the same find result is:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /V /C:"www.r2rdownload.com" /C:"www.elephantafiles.com" "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

The command line to find additionally empty lines anywhere in file and so do not output those lines is:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /V "www\.r2rdownload\.com www\.elephantafiles\.com ^$" "%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

All three space separated strings are regular expression strings in this case which is the reason for escaping `.` with a backslash character to be interpreted as literal character.

The entire batch file could be for example:

```
@echo off
set "HostsFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -r "%HostsFile%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /V "www\.r2rdownload\.com www\.elephantafiles\.com ^$" "%HostsFile%" >"%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
move /Y "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" "%HostsFile%"
if errorlevel 1 del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
set "HostsFile="
```

This batch file must be executed with elevated privileges of an administrator.